# Individual connection speeds

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, asp-classic

I am running Windows 2003 Server. If I download a large file from the server in FireFox the connection maxes out at 100kB per second. If I download the same file from Internet Explorer at the same time, it also maxes out at 100kB per second. Therefore I am transferring 200kB per second from the one server on my internet connection to the same computer. If I also download in another browser like Google Chrome I get a similar result.

Is there some kind of IIS setting that is limiting the speed per connection, maybe something that is meant to save bandwidth for other users? The server is hosted with Peer1 with a 100MBps connection so it is supposed to be pretty fast. There is no other traffic on the server while I am running this test.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There's all sorts of reasons why this might be the case. You might have 100 MBps at both ends - but what's going on the middle? And that's before you consider any policy restrictions at either end.

The only thing you really have much control over at the client is the [TCP Window scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_window_scale_option) - which can result in fast connections with (relatively) high latency giving poor throughput. Note that all nodes on the connection must be capable of supporting rfc 1323.